# Find all records where first_name column does NOT start with A-Z

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I need to extract a subset of results where the value for the `first_name` column starts with anything other than standard English alphabet letters (i.e. A-Z), for example `È`. I am banging my head against a brick wall with this - for example, this is how I've been able to get all the records starting with the letter `A`:

```
@results = User.where("first_name LIKE ?", "A%").order("first_name ASC")
```

Any help would be wonderful.

*EDIT: I am using a PostgreSQL database.*

Comment: Can you provide your Database system name? MySQL? PostGreSQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `~` operator to match regular expression. `~` is used to match `case sensitive` data. So in your case `first_name ~ '^[^A-Z]'` will give `users` whose `first_name` doesn't start with `A-Z`. To match `case insensitive` you need to use `~*`.

```
  @results = User.where("first_name ~ ?", "^[^A-Z]").order("first_name ASC")
```

or

You can also use `!~` which gives the unmatched results (i.e.) `first_name !~ ^[A-Z]` equivalent to `first_name ~ ^[^A-Z]`. To match `case insensitive` use `!~*`.

```
  @results = User.where("first_name !~ ?", "^[A-Z]").order("first_name ASC")
```

For more information see [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly, I have been down with the flu sorry it took me so long to get this reply, it really helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Postgresql

`@results = User.where("first_name SIMILAR TO ?", "[A-Z]%"`)

More info [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-BRACKET-EXPRESSIONS).